# Unable to parse serial port output between ISO 7816 and Reader

Tags: serial-port, smartcard

I'm trying to interpret the communication between an ISO 7816 type card and the card reader. I've connected inline between the card and the reader when i dump the ouput to console i'm getting data that that im not expecting, see below:

Action: Card inserted to reader, expect an ATR only

Expected output:

```
3B 65 00 00 B0 40 40 22 00
```

Actual Output:

```
E0 3B 65 00 B0 40 40 22 00 90 00 80 9B 80 E0 E2
```

The 90 00 is the standard for OK that it reset, but why i am still logging additional data both before the ATR (E0) as well as data after

Answer (score 0):

The communication line is documented in ISO 7816-3 (electrical interface and transmission protocols), look for the respective chapters of T=0 or T=1 protocol. T=1 is a block oriented protocol involving a prolog containing node addresses and an epilog containing a CRC/LRC.

For the ATR however, no protocol is running yet, since here the information is contained, which protocols the card supports, for the terminal to choose. Surely so early 90 00 is no SW1/SW2.

Comment: Any tools that will be useful in trying to sniff out the APDUs or the user zone memory? I was hopefully that after the handshake completes that i could intercept the user zone memory and get the card to dump it after it authenticates with the machine.

Comment: @DDulla: No way, if the card would dump user memory, you would not need a sniffer, but a simple smart card reader would do. But smart cards are excatly designed to prevent such an unauthorized access. My guess is, that there are more interesting research tasks, but your milage may vary.